# X-Frame-Options without blocking one directory [NGINX]

Tags: nginx

I'm new to Nginx. I want to block the iframe option of my website except for one */images* directory. How can I do this using X-Frame-Options?

Answer (score 0):

With [ngx_security_headers](https://github.com/GetPageSpeed/ngx_security_headers):

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    security_headers on;
    location /images/ {
        security_headers off;
    }
}
```

Without ngx_security_headers module:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    location /images/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "";
        # important, add any other add_header from outer scope 
        # so that they are not "lost"
    }
}
```

Comment: I add it like in without ngx_security_headers module. When I tried to iframe /images/file.html I got "www.domain.com refused to connect.". I use chrome browser. Any ideas?

Comment: That is probably unrelated. Check if your configuration is valid, e.g. `nginx -t`, your firewall, etc.

Comment: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: I use Cloudflare. Can it be a problem?

Comment: You need basic troubleshooting. Is NGINX running? `systemctl status nginx`. Does it listen on both 443 and 80 ports? `telnet localhost 80` and `telnet localhost 443`. Can you do the same externally? `telnet <server IP> 80`. Can you do the same via Cloudflare? `telnet <domain name> 80`, etc. etc.

Comment: telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: I don't know what should I do

Comment: telnet localhost 80, telnet localhost 443, telnet <server IP> 80, telnet <domain name> the same output